# Slowing down MongoDB shell output for large documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I am trying to inspect a document that is larger than the print buffer for the Windows command window. For some queries more allows you to type `it` for more output. Is there a way to apply this to other commands?

For instance I might do `db.coll.findOne()` which greatly surpasses the print buffer. I'd like to see as much as fits, type `it`, see more, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this workaround:

Make a file with your command... i.e. **tmp.txt** containing

```
db.coll.findOne()
```

Then execute the query via command line - piping the output to an output text file like this:

```
mongo yourDatabaseName < tmp.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: This works for now, thanks. I'll wait a day or two to accept in case there is a shell method to do this.

Comment: I looked through the cursor methods here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/js-cursor/

as well as settings for document/size limits but couldn't seem to find anything.

Also if you're going to use a query which returns more than 20 results - add .toArray().  Definitely let me know if you find something.

Answer (score 1):

You can always extend you windows terminal's buffer.

At left top corner, click right mouse button and select properties.
At layout tab, you can change "Screen buffer size" to width 9999 and height 9999, that's quite big scroll back buffer... 
Same time you can enlarge your "window size" to cover whole screen (if you want) and change your font to smaller (you can fit more text to screen).